# how to use rest api to create extension api on Bonita BPM

Tags: bonita

I have one extension api, I upload it form web/resource/REST API, affter upload, it works well. however, I used the code to upload, i used the PageAPI.createPage() to upload extension, it upload success, but it doesn' work, I check the file on server, from the server, I can't find the extension from the `${BONITA_HOME}\bonita\client\tenants\1\work`, it only exist on `${BONITA_HOME}\bonita\client\tenants\1\temp`, debug, the files is invode the pageAPI servlet, and invode the PageDataStore.createEngieenPage(), so my question is how can i use the REST API to add extension and deploy it?

Comment: Please, consider providing a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to deploy a Bonita REST API extension programmatically you need to:

- Call the `loginservice` REST API for authentication
- Send the file to a temporary folder on server side using the `uploadPage` servlet
- Register the new REST API extension by calling the `portal/page` REST API

I create a basic [Groovy script that demonstrate that](https://github.com/Bonitasoft-Community/example-upload-rest-api-extension).